# Box and whisker graph in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Is there a way to draw a Box and Whisker graph in Excel?

Comment: Check out my tutorial [Excel Box and Whisker Diagrams (Box Plots)](http://peltiertech.com/excel-box-and-whisker-diagrams-box-plots/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In a new worksheet, type the following data:

   ```
    A1: Statistic   B1: a    C1: b    D1: c
    A2: median      B2: 40   C2: 45   D2: 50
    A3: q1          B3: 20   C3: 22   D3: 30
    A4: min         B4: 10   C4: 15   D4: 18
    A5: max         B5: 100  C5: 110  D5: 90
    A6: q3          B6: 70   C6: 75   D6: 57
   ```
2. Select cells A1:D6. On the Insert menu, click Chart.
3. On the Standard types tab, click Stock under Chart type, and then click the fourth chart sub-type.

   The following explanation appears below the chart sub-type:

   > Volume-Open-High-Low-Close. Requires five series of values in this order.
4. Click Next.
5. On the Data Range tab, click Rows under Series in, and then click Next.
6. On the Legend tab, click to clear the Show legend check box.
7. On the Axes tab, click to clear the Value (Y) Axis check box under Secondary axis, and then click Finish.
8. Click once on any one of the colored columns to select the series. Do not click one of the white columns.
9. On the Chart menu, click Chart Type. Under Chart type, click Line, and then click OK.

   > A line that connects the three white columns appears in the chart.

10.Click once on the line, and then click Selected Data Series on the Format menu.

[source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155130)

[Reference](http://blog.immeria.net/2007/01/box-plot-and-whisker-plots-in-excel.html)